# Extracting the frequencies in percentage

Tags: r

Here are some dataframe with volume in numerical numbers

```
data.frame(class = ("a","b","a","b"), date = c(2009,2009,2010,2010), volume=c(1,1,2,0))
```

How is it possible to convert the volume column to be in percentage for the same year(date) of different labels?

```
data.frame(class = ("a","b","a","b"), date = c(2009,2009,2010,2010), volumepercentage=c("50.00%","50.00%","100.00%","9.00%"))
```

Comment: Do you need `df1 %>% group_by(date) %>% mutate(volumnepercentage = 100 * volume/sum(volume))`

Comment: The `9%` for the last row is not clear

Comment: Please show what you've tried, since this isn't totally clear, and what research you've done, since I imagine there are many other SO posts that should at least help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R approach:

```
df1.spl <- split(df1, df1$date)
df1.lst <- lapply(df1.spl, function(x) data.frame(x, pct=prop.table(x$volume)*100))
df2 <- do.call(rbind, df1.lst)
df2
#        class date volume pct
# 2009.1     a 2009      1  50
# 2009.2     b 2009      1  50
# 2010.3     a 2010      2 100
# 2010.4     b 2010      0   0
```

Note the change in the row names. The command `rownames(df2) <- NULL` will remove them.